# Transfer Array index to next controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have one array.getting images from that array i want to transfer the array index to  next method how can i do this.

my code:-

```
FrontsCards =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:13];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub1.png" atIndex:0];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub2.png" atIndex:1];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub3.png" atIndex:2];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub4.png" atIndex:3];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub5.png" atIndex:4];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub6.png" atIndex:5];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub7.png" atIndex:6];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub8.png" atIndex:7];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub9.png" atIndex:8];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub10.png" atIndex:9];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub11.png" atIndex:10];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub12.png" atIndex:11];
    [FrontsCards insertObject:@"cloub13.png" atIndex:12];
```

randomly fetched all the images and store the imageview scroll vertically

```
    randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];

    NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];

   [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

if the user douuble tapped on cloub12.png image i want to genrate the 11 index value and transfer it to the next view controller.
if user tapped cloub4 index genrate the 3

how may i do this thanks in advance.

Comment: just set tag for all imageview and add UITabGestureReognizer when user tabs get tag and send to next viewcontroller

Comment: i have single imageview

Comment: @JitendraDeore  why can't u make use of `randIdx` and pass this value to other view controller.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. However, that is the longest way to add objects to an array. You can use addObject: (which just adds to the end of the array), initWithObjects: (which will init the array with the list of objects), or use the new @[] syntax to create the array.

Comment: i want to display all image randomly when user start new that's why i used randIdx.

Comment: if the user doubble tapped on cloub2.png i want 1 index value. that is my question.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property, and synthesize it in your NextViewController

`@property(nonatomic)NSInteger tagValue;`

First set tag to your imageView

```
[ImgView setTag:randIdx];
```

Add Gesture rec to yourImageView

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
     tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
     tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
     tap.delegate = self;
     [ImgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then on your double tapGesture , get tag value of yourImage then

// handle method

```
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[gestureRecognizer view];
    NSLog(@"Pass this tag=%d",image.tag);

    NextViewController *NVC=[[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
    NVC.tagValue=yourImageView.tag;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:NVC animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: i want if user dobble tapped on particular image i want that image value

Comment: – Rajneesh071  if the user tapped on cloub10.png image i want the 9 value that's my requirement.

Comment: u undrerstand my requirement

Comment: yes, according to your question , you are inserting cloub10 image at 9 index of array, and we are also setting tagValue to your image view as your index(e.g 9) , then getting this gegValue.

Comment: no that all image changes randomly so how may i get the image index value

Comment: when you are setting image to your imageView , that time you have to change tagValue of your imageView

Comment: each an every time images randomly changed but tag value not change.

Comment: when ever you are randomly changing your image setTag value of you imageView to your random no.

Comment: no no i get the idea from your code if you want to support me.then upvote if not then dont upvote me k

Comment: hmmm SO team will reduce your point if they will find you to said other one for up voting :)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass any kind of data to anywhere in the app through creating `@property` in `appDelegate`.
           For example if you want to pass any integer data to some view controller.You have to create `@property` at the `appDelegate`---

in `appDelegate.h`----

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)int someObj;
```

in `appDelegate.m`-----

```
@synthesize someObj;
```

and then you can access this object where you want int the app by importing the appDelegate class and you have to create an object of singleton class (appDelegate) like this

```
AppDelegateClass  *appDelegate= [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

appDelegate.someObj=_theValueWhichYouToPass(/*here the value is integer*/).


//this assignment gives u this value anywhere you want through the object of appDelegate...

NSLog(@"%d",appDelegateObj.someObj);
```

You can use this value as you like..

```
              Hope this will help u very much ......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];
     NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];
     [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
     ImgView.tag=randIdx;

     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
     tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
     tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
     tap.delegate = self;
     [ImgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
     [tap release];

     ImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

   // handle method
   - (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { 
      UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[gestureRecognizer view];
       UIImage *image = [imageView image];
       NSLog(@"Pass this tag=%d",image.tag);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass index to nextviewController by overriding the init methods as given,

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if(self) {

    self.index = index;
}

return self;
```

}

Or

```
- (id)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

self = [super init];

if(self) {

    self.index = index;
}

return self;
```

}

Comment: i want the user doubble tapped value

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Rajneesh071 answer set

```
randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];
NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:randIdx];
[ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
//ADD THE TAG
[ImgView setTag:randIdx];
```

Comment: i want the doubble tapped value of image

Comment: what does that mean , you want the UIImage object ,imageName or the imageIndex you tapped ?

Comment: @Jitendra : Mate when you are having the index why can't you get the image value from your FrontCards array.

Comment: i want that imageindex where user doubble tapped.